# How do I stop my sheet from being randomly filled by =SUM(-1,1)?

Tags: google-sheets

This is some sort of very strange bug. I am creating a spreadsheet using conditional formatting and colour-coding: in one (and only one) of the columns, the cells are randomly and *automatically* filling up with a light-green background and the contents '=SUM(-1,1)' ('0'). The only thing that I could imagine to be causing this is that I added the Power Tools Add-On in order to count cell colour in each row, but the process is continuing even after having removed the Add-On.

Please let me know any other information I can provide that may help, but I haven't done much of anything - other than the Add-On, this has just happened!

Answer (score 1):

Solution by using "brute-force"

1. Remove all scripts from your spreadsheet
2. Remove all add-ons

Details:

Remove all scripts from your spreadsheet

1. To remove all the scripts click on Tools > Script editor,
2. - If a list of projects is shown, do the following for each one.
   - If the script project hasn't a title, close the tab/window.
   - If the script project has code then click on File > Delete project (note this can't be undone)

Remove all add-ons from the spreadsheet

1. Click on the Add-ons menu
2. Click on Manage add-ons
3. Click on the green Manage buttons, then on Use on this document to un-check the option